# JFreeChart with SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jfreechart

I'm developping a plugin for eclipse and extending the org.eclipse.ui.views extension point. I want to use JFreeChart for drawing some graphics in eclipse view. 
Is it possible to use JFreeChart with SWT in eclipse view ?

Comment: I found two jar file (jfreechart-1.0.13-experimental.jar, jfreechart-1.0.13-swt.jar) and some demo codes about SWT in JFreeChart download. It says that jfreechart-1.0.13-swt.jar includes specific JFreeChart SWT classes. It might be an answer to my question. I'll try using them..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The [Eclipse-CS plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) does this if you want to see how it works.

Here is an example screen shot:

[image: Eclipse CS screenshot]

Comment: Are the graphics drawed by JFreeChart?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at it last, but I believe they are

Comment: Here's the cvsweb page of the relevant source file.  They use the SWT_AWT bridge, which is one way of doing it.

http://eclipse-cs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/eclipse-cs/CheckstyleStatsPlugin/src/net/sf/eclipsecs/stats/views/GraphStatsView.java?revision=1.9&view=markup