# Scrollable JFree domain axis and custom marker label

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have this code to draw graph, this works fine. I need two things here

1. on domain axis (x) I want to be able to scroll.
2. On markers I see a thick bold line. I want to be able to see some readable text for this marker.

For now I see this output
[image]

and upon zooming I see this

[image]

3. Also on domain axis I have millis values. can I map it to human readable dates ?

   ```
   public class Grapher extends ApplicationFrame {

       public Grapher(final String title, List<PriceModel> priceModels) {

           super(title);
           final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("foo");
           double max = Double.MIN_VALUE, min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
           for (int i = 0; i < priceModels.size(); i++) {
               double price = priceModels.get(i).getPrice();
               if (price < min) {
                   min = price;
               }
               if (price > max) {
                   max = price;
               }
               series.add((double) priceModels.get(i).getDate(), price);
           }

           final XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
           final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                   "XY Series Demo",
                   "X",
                   "Y",
                   data,
                   PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                   true,
                   true,
                   false
           );

           for (int i = 0; i < priceModels.size(); i++) {
               if (priceModels.get(i).getAction() != null) {
                   Marker marker = new ValueMarker((double) priceModels.get(i).getDate());
                   marker.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
                   marker.setLabelTextAnchor(TextAnchor.TOP_RIGHT);

                   if (priceModels.get(i).getAction() == Types.Action.SELL) {
                       marker.setPaint(Color.green);
                       marker.setLabel("SELL");
                   } else {
                       marker.setPaint(Color.red);
                       marker.setLabel("BUY");
                   }
                   marker.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10.0f));
                   chart.getXYPlot().addDomainMarker(marker);
               }
           }
           chart.getXYPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
           chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer().setPaint(Color.BLUE);
           chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setRange(min - 1, max + 1);
           final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
           chartPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(true);
           chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
           setContentPane(chartPanel);
       }

       public static void draw(List<PriceModel> priceModels) {
           final Grapher demo = new Grapher("foo", priceModels);
           demo.pack();
           RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
           demo.setVisible(true);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `chartPane` in a `JScrollPane`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do I do it ?

Comment: [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'd look at a few other things before scroll pane; more below.

Comment: @trashgod Have to admit I've not really used JFreeChart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to combine several approaches:

1. **Domain scrolling alternatives**:

   - Try a [`SlidingXYDataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393652/230513), implemented [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/patches/231/) and illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46130344/230513).
   - Enable panning, e.g. `plot.setDomainPannable(true)`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284972/230513).
   - Look at [paging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).
   - Use a [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), e.g. `add(new JScrollPane(chartPanel);`.
2. **Marker text**: Use `XYTextAnnotation`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18328489/230513).
3. **Format dates**: Replace the factory's axis with a `DateAxis` and use `setDateFormatOverride()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106979/230513).

Comment: are you suggesting all 4 points for scrolling are needed or these are options ?

Comment: They represent alternatives; I usually just enable panning.

Comment: Thanks, in my case time is on X axis. It only allows DateAxis on Y.

Comment: I don't understand. The implementation of `SlidingXYDataset` cited above shows `NumberAxis` in the first demo and `DateAxis` in the second demo; both are the domain axis.

Comment: Thanks @trashgod. can you help here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150322/jfreechart-with-selectable-domain-axis-and-zoom ?