# How to display only "last 24 hours" from a "last 72 hours" JFreeChart TimeSeries

Tags: java, time-series, jfreechart, simpledateformat, timeserieschart

I wrote these 2 lines of code to create a chart using an `XYDataset`:

```
final XYDataset dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(myInfo.getSeries());
JFreeChart timechart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(myInfo.getName()
    + " CPU (last 72h)", "", "CPU %", dataset, false, false, false);
```

These lines created this nice "last 72h" chart:

[image: last 72hrs chart]

This is how I added the information to build this chart (this piece of code can run multiple times):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateAsStringToParse);
Second second = new Second(date);
myInfo.getSeries().addOrUpdate(second, maxValue); // maxValue is an Integer
```

I want a (seemingly) simple alteration—to "cut" this only to the last 24 hours. I mean to see only the most "recent" 24 hours in the graph, like so (in the picture is a different chart I made using the same technique, but the information exists only for the last 24hrs):

[image: last 24hrs chart]

I have looked through the API and could not find an appropriate answer, as I believe this should have some clever but simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *discarding* old data, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513), it looks like you want to display a contiguous subset of the data, as if looking through a window. While [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/SlidingCategoryDataset.html) provides this feature for a `CategoryDataset`, there is no built-in solution for an `XYDataset`. `SlidingXYDataset`, seen [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/patches/231/), maybe an alternative. In the variation of `SliderDemo2` illustrated below, I've added three days of data to a single series with a one day window. I've retained the slider for easy review of earlier values.

```
static final int COUNT = 3 * 24 * 60;
public static final int WINDOW = 24 * 60;
public static final int FIRST = 2 * 24 * 60;
…
this.slider.setValue(FIRST);
```

[image]

As an aside, note that some classes have moved since the patch was submitted:

```
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;
```

> Can't I *just* use `setMaximumItemAge()`?

Not in isolation; `addOrUpdate()`, *et al.*, calls `removeAgedItems(false)` before notifying listeners.

> I am using `Second`.

Threes days of `Second` data, e.g., would imply `setMaximumItemAge(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)`.

> A sliding window might not be available to me since I am saving the chart as a JPEG.

You can pass the desired `firstItemIndex` as a parameter to the `SlidingXYDataset` constructor;  you can update the index later via `setFirstItemIndex()` if needed.

Comment: Thank you! Can't I just use `setMaximumItemAge()` though? I understand that I am using `Second` so I will have to use `setMaximumItemAge(86400)` ? I am asking since the solution of a sliding window might not be available to me since I am saving the chart as a JPEG...

Comment: I am still not 100% on this. What does "not in _isolation_" mean? I have actually just tested setting maximum age of 86400 on a 3-day chart and it worked perfectly (showed just last 24 hours of data instead of 3 days...). To clarify, I added all the information normally, and just before `new TimeSeriesCollection(series);` I set `series.setMaximumItemAge(86400);`

Comment: Yeah I see but it only discards _if_ I set the `setMaximumItemAge`, otherwise the default is `9223372036854775807L` which is basically all the information...